# How to use polyfill in visualforce component?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, javascript-debugging

Link to polyfill: https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill
The polyfill is to allow increment decrement buttons in Internet explorer for

I added the .js and .css file from the polyfill as a static resource.

```
     <apex:component controller="cxp_ctrl_ConfigureProduct">
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.inputnumber}"/>
     <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.inputnumbercss}"/>
```

But I cannot see any increment decrement arrows in IE Browser. What may I be missing?

Comment: Have you disabled standard stylesheet of VF ?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal yes

Comment: In my experience, IE browser is the only browser that is not good with SF styling. Have you tried updating it to the latest available version? Also, try to clear history/cache memory and try.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. What may you suggest to resolve this? Apparently, the increment/decrement arrows are available by default in Chrome browser, but they're not supported in IE.

Comment: I am not sure. May be you should also consider posting this in the stackoverflow with *JavaScript* related tags. I would also research online something like: make the CSS work without cross-browser compatibility issues. Better luck.

Comment: is jQuery also included?

Comment: @kurunve yess I have included jquery script src but I'm receiving the jquery not defined error

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in this manner. We can add the cdn in visualforce page.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-polyfills/0.1.42/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```